# Postfix seems to ignore mynetworks?

Tags: networking, security, postfix

I have a site, which relays automated emails from external system to pass on via authenticated SMTP of our provider.

Recently the external system went haywire and started to generate hundreds of emails every x minutes.

I wanted to temporary remove its ability to send me email, so I removed it from mynetworks in all the main.cf.* files (main.cf  main.cf.smtps  main.cf.tls). And of course restarted postfix.

So, mynetworks WAS:

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.XXX.0/24 192.168.YYY.0/24 192.168.ZZZ.0/24 ANOTHER_EXTERNAL_IP/32 **OFFENDING_IP/32** 192.168.NNN.0/24

And now it is:

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.XXX.0/24 192.168.YYY.0/24 192.168.ZZZ.0/24 ANOTHER_EXTERNAL_IP/32 192.168.NNN.0/24

**However, the offending site was still able to connect and drop mail. What gives?**

Every bit of help appreciated

A postcat of offending message:

```
named_attribute: log_ident=AEF9D22E1D
named_attribute: rewrite_context=remote
sender: info@mysite
named_attribute: log_client_name=unknown
named_attribute: log_client_address=OFFENDING_IP
named_attribute: log_client_port=50310
named_attribute: log_message_origin=unknown[OFFENDING_IP]
named_attribute: log_helo_name=[127.0.0.1]
named_attribute: log_protocol_name=ESMTP
named_attribute: client_name=unknown
named_attribute: reverse_client_name=unknown
named_attribute: client_address=OFFENDING_IP
named_attribute: client_port=50310
named_attribute: helo_name=[127.0.0.1]
named_attribute: protocol_name=ESMTP
named_attribute: client_address_type=2
named_attribute: dsn_orig_rcpt=rfc822;SENDTO@email.com
original_recipient: SENDTO@email.com
recipient: SENDTO@email.com
```

Comment: This sounds a bit like you trusted your configuration to not override a parameter by specifying it twice. Use the `postconf` binary to print out *effective* config as suggested in the tag description.

Comment: consider posting your master.cf and the output of the "postconf " command as well as some logs so you can be helped more effectively